# Typecript error: invalid format: Integer too large

Tags: typescript, blockchain, smartcontracts

I'am having trouble with Neo One Framework for Neo Smart Contracts using Typescript.
I'am becoming this error "**Deploy → Invalid format: Integer too large: 66547 > 65536:-32603** ".
There is no line number where this problem occurs, and sometimes it seems like that this error is randomly called.

This is the line in which it occurs now.  this.orderExist()..:

```
public sendORDERS(orderId : Fixed<8>, actorAddress : Address){
    if(this.onlyBy(actorAddress) &&
    this.orderExist(orderId, false)){   //error
        //
        // only comments
    }
}
```

called function looks like this:

```
 @constant
public orderExist (orderId: Fixed<8>, state: boolean){
    const currentState = this.getOrderState(orderId);
    if(currentState == 0 && state == false) 
        return true;  
    else if(currentState != 0 && state == true){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and getOrderState() looks like this:

```
  @constant
public getOrderState(orderId: number): Fixed<8>{
    const state = this.orderState.get(orderId);
    return state === undefined ? 0 : state;
}
```

Any ideas?
I'm using typescript 3.6.3 , it should be compatible with Neo One Framework.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my contracts was too large (too much code). This also caused the "unknown error".

> This is a known limitation of smart contracts. There's a hard limit on
> smart contract sizes (in bytecode) and there's also a similar
> difficulty with compiling large contracts that has to do with the
> NeoVM max number size The way around this is to only do logic in your
> smart contract that absolutely must be executed on the blockchain (ie.
> in the NeoVM) Or you can split your smart contract into multiple smart
> contracts that then call each other for different logic.

- Spencer Corwin